# Wordpress Installation

Tags: installation, local-installation

First of all, I am not a techie so be nice to me please. I am trying to install Wordpress. I have followed the installation instructions for Wordpress as best as I could. However when I try to open localhost on Wampserver, I get a message:

> The website cannot display

The one thing that I believe may be wrong is in the wp-config.php file, I am not sure what to put in "MySQL database username".  I put "`root`" as in the example. Any ideas?

Comment: You have followed http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind, is that you haven't set up an actual database to link the wordpress to so please follow this steps:

navigate in your browser to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` (I hope it is installed)

Create a database with the name wordpress (or whatever else you want)

Navigate to your wordpress directory on localhost and re-enter the database details with root as the database username and 'wordpress' as the database name, fresh installs of wamp do not have a password set so leave that field blank.

I hope this get's you at least on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you WAMP knowledge is good, and you are acquainted with phpMyAdmin.

Open your browser and type: `http://localost/phpmyadmin`

Create a new database and name it whatever you like. Suppose we are taking '`wordpress`' as name. Just hit create database. You are done.

[Download the WordPress latest version](http://wordpress.org/download/), and it. Cut the `wordpress` folder to `C:\\local_path\www\` and Paste it.

Now browse from the browser: `http://localhost/wordpress`

- Install WordPress...
- Database name: 'wordpress' (as our db name is wordpress)
- Username: 'root' (as default username is root)
- Password: '' (as default password is blank)
- Database Prefix: 'wp_' (don't worry about it now)

Install WordPress. And you are done. :)

I've written a [Bangla Tutorial on WAMP Localhost WordPress installation](http://tuts.nanodesignsbd.com/wordpress-installation-into-computer-localhost/), you may not understand Bangla, but you can see the screenshots. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all , make sure a Database is created ,  you can do this via phpmyadmin , grant permissions over the DB to a User and then mention the DB name and the DB user with the password in the WP-config.php, this should fix the issue.